# Android navigation plays animation when not needed

Tags: android, androidx

In my application I use Android Jetpack Navigation components.
User navigates from `master` to `detail` fragment with animations and it works properly.

Now a user have the option to navigate to a completely different fragment using Navigation bar. 
And Navigation library plays exit animation of `detail` fragment.

While it corresponds with master - detail relations it doesn't correspond with anything else.

Is there a way to completely suppress exit animation or change it? I don't want to play `detail` animation when switching to specific fragment.

As a workaround currently I use `fade_out` exit animation cause it's more or less UX neutral.

Comment: don't set these property in advance
set them according to your need

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, to solve it I've added `androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx`in gradle.

Hope it can help you